# SSRS Reports Group by (Formatting)

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, group-by

Hi am new to SQL Server (SSRS) reports.
 I have a table of Users with 3 colums (Id Name and RecieptNo), e.g.

```
ID     Name           RecieptNo
 1      Charles        0001
 1      Charles        0002
 1      Charles        0003
 2      Harry          0004
 2      Harry          0005
```

I have to make a report that looks like this

```
Name       RecieptNo
Charles    0001
           0002
           0003
________________________
Harry      0004
           0005
```

can anyone help on how to format or group the id, name

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a pretty standard SSRS report.

Start by creating a new table in the designer:

[image]

I've deleted a couple of columns that aren't required here.

Next, add a new Row Group based on ID:

[image]

[image]

It should look something like this:

[image]

Next, change the *ID* field to *Name* and clean up the headers:

[image]

End result looks like your requirement:

[image]

Comment: Did this help your issue at all?